# c# how to refresh datagridview properly

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview

I'm working on a project, in this project i need to use sql databases. I got a method for insertion and its working properly. But i want to refresh my datagridview after insertion with a Display() method.Now, there is the code:

```
 private void Display()
    {
        this.packetsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Packets);           
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```

What i have to do to fix it help plz.

Comment: Is that giving as error ?

Comment: gives an exception but its problem is it doesnt updates and refreshes the datagridview.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to re-bind the dataset to gridview like

```
this.packetsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet);           
dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dataGridView1.DataSource = this.database1DataSet;
```

Comment: @GökberkAçıkgöz, yeah absolutely

Answer (score 0):

you must load dataGridView1.DataSource after add one item.
look like this method:

```
 this.packetsTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.Packets);//your code 
LoadData();
```

.    .    .

```
public void LoadData()
     {    
      dataGridView1.DataSource=// load data
     }
```